# Running wxpython app in cygwin/X

Tags: python, cygwin, gtk, wxpython

I have installed and tried both `wxpython-3.0` and `wxpython-2.8` for `python2.7` from the standard `cygwin` repos (64-bit, Win 7). However when I start the Cygwin X server and try to run the most simple "Hello World" script from [wxPython tutorials](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started):

```
# test.py
import wx

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

I get a `Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set` which eventually ends in a `segmentation fault`.

The `DISPLAY` variable is set to `:0` (`export DISPLAY=:0`) and corresponds to the started X server.

Is wxPython broken in `cygwin` or is some other procedure necessary prior to launching a script using wxPython?

Comment: did you follow the build instructions for gtk with cygwin in this doc: https://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html

Comment: No, I have taken all packets from the cygwin repos. Haven't built anything from src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and got it working for my cygwin64 installation. I used

- python v2.7.14 and
- cygwin package python-2-wx version 3.0.2.0-3

Both installed via the cygwin installer.
I also have the python-2-wx2.8 in my cygwin install, and I can select which one is to be used by creating the file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx.pth containing only one line specifying the relative path to the package to be imported by the "import wx" line:

```
wx-3.0-gtk3
```

or

```
wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
```

When I use the later (wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode) I get the same error as you mention, "assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed", but when I use wx-3.0-gtk3 the errors disappear and the script runs fine and I can see the graphics in my X-window.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your X server with the `startxwin` command instead of `xinit`.

```
startxwin &

export DISPLAY=:0.0

./test.py
```

I was able to get your test code running with this sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately this gave the same error :-(. All packages from cygwin?

Comment: @fnokke - I just grabbed python-wx-tools and let it grab whatever other dependencies it wanted.  Looks like those included python-wx2.8 and the associated libwx libraries of the same version.  When using the `xinit` to launch the windows system, it launched a single large window in which an initial xterm was displayed.  Running `test.py` gave me similar errors to what you saw.  When I used `startxwin`, it launched in multiwindow mode the python code worked fine.

Comment: Strange I tried the same thing and I still get the error. I thought first it could be since actually I had been trying `python-wx3.0` but I tried `python-wx2.8` and got the same error.

Comment: @fnokke - Not sure how useful it is, but I checked my python version, which comes up as Python 2.7.12.  If I go back to using `xinit` and look at the errors, my first one reads `(process:14564): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed, which I believe is a little different from the one you saw?  Let me know if there is something else you want me to experiment with, or other information to dig up.

Comment: Strange. I had a colleague (who runs native Windows 7) double check and he also gets the same errors as me with your example. The python version is the same. And you also run cygwin-x86_64? I wonder what else could cause this discrepancy...

Comment: @fnokke - I am indeed running cygwin-x86_64, although I am  on Windows 10 instead of Windows 7.  Not sure that would make a difference, but something must be.  Hmmm.  I don't use the X server regularly at all, although I have run doxywizard a handful of times. As a result, I don't really have much in the way of X-specific dotfiles or environment variables outside of DISPLAY.

Comment: @fnokke Well, now my frustration is right up there with yours.  Tried getting this to run on a second machine and I can't.  Exactly the same issue you're running into.  I have no idea why it is working on one of my machines but not the other.  Horribly frustrating.  I'll have to give it another go this weekend.

Comment: @fnokke - Well, I hate to say it, but my conclusion is there must be something horribly wrong with the Cygwin version of wx.  Here's a workaround that seems pretty easy, although it's outside of Cygwin.  I just installed miniconda with Python 2.7 and added the package wxpython.  Ran your code from a windows-style prompt and it worked great.  (Seemingly with no X server running anywhere.)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this. I guess it means that indeed cygwin wxpython is broken and that a workaround - i.e. not using cygwin, is necessary.

Comment: @fnokke - No problem.  Was an interesting exercise.